# Problems with child and brackets

Tags: flutter

Morning guys,
I´ve problems with bracket and childs. When I combined Containers, Center and Stack and so on , it shows me most of the time red lines under some words. It´s always luck when I can solve it. Here is a part of my code where I will show you what I mean..
The problem is the first child after children:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
           body: Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     image: DecorationImage(
                         image: AssetImage("assets/kreis.jpeg"), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
     
                  child:  Stack(
                       children: <Widget>[
                         child:Container(

               Center(

                 Visibility(
                     child: Text("Gone"),
                     visible: visibleT,
                   child:Container(

                   height: 150,
                   width: 150,
     
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   shape: BoxShape.circle,
                   image: DecorationImage(
                     image: AssetImage("assets/T.jpeg"),fit: BoxFit.fill),
                 ),
                 
                 ),
                 
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    child: Text("Gone") ,
                    visible: visibleB,
                    child:Container(
                       height: 150,
                   width: 150,
     
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   shape: BoxShape.circle,
                   image: DecorationImage(
                     image: AssetImage("assets/B.png"),fit: BoxFit.fill),
                 ),
                 
                 ),


                    ),
                Visibility(
                  child:Text("Gone"),
                  visible: visibleH,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                   width: 150,
     
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   shape: BoxShape.circle,
                   image: DecorationImage(
                     image: AssetImage("assets/h.png"),fit: BoxFit.fill),
                 ),
                 
                 ),


                    

                  ) 
                  ),
                  

                 
                   
                        Positioned(
                             right: 150,
                             top: 150,
                             width: 60,
                             height: 70,
     
                            
             
             child: FloatingActionButton( 
               onPressed:
                 _listen,
                 // setState(() { searchWord="Tinte";});
                 // getText();
                     
               child:  Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none),
                              )
                               
                        ),
                        
                         
                              
                           Positioned(
                             left: 100,
                             bottom: 10,
                             child:  Container(
                   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     color: Colors.cyanAccent[100],
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                   ),
                   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                     vertical: 8.0,
                     horizontal: 12.0,
                   ),
                   child: Text(
                     _text,
                     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                             
                            )    
                             
                             )
                             
                           )
                
                
                       
                         )
                       ]
                  )
                  
           )
         );
         
         
       }
```

this is not the end, but I think this was the critical part

Answer (score 0):

Some widget only allow multiple children, in your code it look like you have multiple child for widget which can only handle one child only. Like stack allow multiple child but container do not allow multiple child. Please check all container code there is multiple child in the container widget.

Edit:
Error free code, please share design for the app so all widgets could be properly aligned.

here is the code

```
 bool _isListening = false;
  bool visibleT = true;
  bool visibleH = true;
  bool visibleB = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Visibility(
                  visible: visibleT,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("Gone"),
                      Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Visibility(
                  visible: visibleB,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("Gone"),
                      Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Visibility(
                  visible: visibleH,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("Gone"),
                      Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
                left: 100,
                bottom: 10,
                child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.cyanAccent[100],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 8.0,
                      horizontal: 12.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Some Text",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                    )))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Positioned(
        right: 150,
        top: 150,
        width: 60,
        height: 70,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: i tried it, i got only 2 problems now. Now the problem is the first Container after my body Container. If I use child it will underline it in a red colour.

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the tree structure in nested widgets!

**Fixed:**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/kreis.jpeg"), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Visibility(
                replacement: Text("Gone"),
                visible: visibleT,
                child: Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/T.jpeg"), fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                ),
              ))),
              Visibility(
                replacement: Text("Gone"),
                visible: visibleB,
                child: Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/B.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                replacement: Text("Gone"),
                visible: visibleH,
                child: Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/h.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  right: 150,
                  top: 150,
                  width: 60,
                  height: 70,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _listen,
                    // setState(() { searchWord="Tinte";});
                    // getText();

                    child: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none),
                  )),
              Positioned(
                  left: 100,
                  bottom: 10,
                  child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.cyanAccent[100],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 8.0,
                        horizontal: 12.0,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        _text,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                      )))
            ])));
  }
```

Comment: thanks! I tried your code, but a get more problems now. "Visibility" , "Positioned", the brackets of " Center" and of "Container" are red lined again

Comment: see your code without any red line here: https://pasteboard.co/JuvToFW.png

Comment: your welcome! please accept the answer if the problem is solved